# What does the shrinkWrap property do in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and very eager to learn this technology. I cannot understand the work of `shrinkWrap` property in `ListView`. I couldn't understand the [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are missing in https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer maybe im dumb but I understood nothing when I read that explanation :)

Comment: The link that @GünterZöchbauer provided no longer works. I believe this is the updated one they tried to link to. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Usually a `ListView` (as well as `GridView`, `PageView` and `CustomScrollView`) tries to fill all the available space given by the parent element, even when the list items would require less space.

With `shrinkWrap: true`, you can change this behavior so that the `ListView` only occupies the space it needs (it will still scroll when there more items).

Take a look at this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(32),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: false,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With `shrinkWrap: false`:

[image: without shrinkWrap]

With `shrinkWrap: true`:

[image: with shrinkWrap]

You can use this in `AlertDialog`s: When there are only a few items, make the dialog as small as possible. When there are many items, fill the screen height and make the list scrollable:

[image: Dialog]

[image: Dialog]

Comment: Beautifully explained, the docs say, 

"Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes."

So one must try to make use of `Expanded` rather than `shrinkWrap` right?

Comment: I am getting an error on iOS when using ListView with shrinkwrap.  (RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions) plz HELP!

Comment: I second @theredcap question with regards to alternatives of using `shrinkWrap: true` - is there any proper workaround for this?

Comment: [Using slivers](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/flutter/avoid-shrink-wrap-in-lists) may be appropriate as an alternative.

Comment: Very good explanation  I wrote a sample: https://dartpad.dev/?id=2302f12831923b65e5a47bea07ea3997

Comment: ShrinkWrap vs Slivers | Decoding Flutter, by the Flutter team
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0

Comment: Does this property `shrinkWrap` affect the performance of the app?

Answer (score 45):

If you do **not** set the `shrinkWrap` property, your `ListView` will be as big as its parent.

If you set it to `true`, the list will wrap its content and be as big as it children allows it to be.

Answer (score 13):

Every ScrollView (ListView , GridView , CustomScrollView) have a shrinkWrap property for determining the size of **scrollDirection**.

So ScrollView's scrollDirection can have 02 sizes.

1. Same size as parent size.
2. Same size as content size (All children size).

If ScrollView's **shrinkWrap : false** , Then ScrollView's scrollDirection size is **same size as parent size**.

If the ScrollView's **shrinkWrap : true** , Then ScrollView's scrollDirection size is **same size as Content size (All children size)**.

**But Why ScrollView scrollDirection is need to switch between these 02 sizes ???**

Reason is ScrollView's parent constraints.

- If ScrollView's parent give an **Tight or Loose constraint** , Then your ScrollView's scrollDirection size is same as its parent size. [shrinkWrap : false].
- If ScrollView's parent give an **Unbound constraint** , Then your ScrollView's scrollDirection size must need to be same as its Content size. [shrinkWrap : true]. *Otherwise it will give an unbound height runtime exception*

Answer (score 4):

By the way, you can add this property to other widgets such as RisedButton to shrinks the tap target size to the minimum provided by the Material specification.

```
materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
```