# How to fill parent to have a listview with spaceBetween

Tags: flutter

I have a list with 5 elements and Iwould like to have a listview with spaceBetween that fills parents height

Now the listview keeps on top and don't fills the parents height

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: new Text(widget.title)),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Dia>>(
        future: _con.getDiaList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Dia> diaList = snapshot.data;

            if (diaList.isNotEmpty) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[buildList(diaList),],
              );
            } else {
              return Text("No hi han dies per mostrar");
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(List<Dia> diaList) => ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: diaList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return buildCard(diaList[index], context);
        },
      );

  Widget buildCard(Dia dia, context) => Card(
        elevation: 8.0,
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 15.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: blueColor),
          child: cardContent(dia, context),
        ),
      );
```

Actual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jIQr.jpg
Expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12tKj.jpg

Comment: You need to set the `shrinkWrap` property to `false`, have a look in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008230/9316075

Comment: I did it and it throws an exception of "given unlimited vertical space (list inside list without height)". Without column now the list fills but it stills renders like the 'actual' image.

Comment: You can solve this exception by wrapping your `buildList(diaList)` in `Expanded` widget, something like this `Expanded(child: buildList(diaList))`.

Comment: Now i have "Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets."
I understand why it needs to be inside a flex widget, but knowing that the list will always have 5 elements and will not exceed vertical size it's weird that it doesn't let you do something like that.