# What, When and How to use MaterialTapTargetSize in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. While I am wandering through flutter docs. I found MaterialTapTargetSize in Button's property. The docs made me confused.

So I want to know

1. what is the usage of MaterialTapTargetSize property?
2. When to use?
3. How to use?

simple English that would be better for me. Thank you

Comment: You can see this answer too:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369979/11675817)

Answer (score 3):

1. The MaterialTapTargetSize property of a widget set an area around a widget to catch gestures etc. The area around the checkbox below is an example.

[image: checkbox with taptarget size]

2. An instance would be when you want this

[image: this]

but you have this

[image]

Notice the space around the checkbox is preventing it from aligning to the start as the TextField above it.

3. ```
    Checkbox(
    value: model.checkboxValue,
    onChanged: (onChanged) {
    model.onCheckboxChecked(onChanged);
    },
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ),
   ```

Note that this reduces the space around the checkbox, it doesn't remove it fully.