# Add a GridView to the end of listview

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter , i am trying to add a GridView to the end of my listview,my goal is in the end of the screen i find the gridview , but i have errors :

```
 The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  GridView file:///C:/Users/Fares/AndroidStudioProjects/tl_fantasy/lib/tl/tl.dart:211:33
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1356:15)
#1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1417:6)
#2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1756:9)
#3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
```

this error show up only when i add in the end of the file the container of gridview

hero my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TL extends StatelessWidget{
  List<String> images = [
    "https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/flutter/images/flutter-logo.png",
    "https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/flutter/images/flutter-logo.png",
    "https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/flutter/images/flutter-logo.png",
    "https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/flutter/images/flutter-logo.png"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])
        ),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              child:  Text(
                "Tunisian League",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Text("Click Here", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),textAlign: TextAlign.right, ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

                        ),

                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  )

                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: images.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return Image.network(images[index]);
                  },
                )
            )

          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

I hope that i can find a solution for that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the 'shrinkWrap' property to the GridView.

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: images.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return Image.network(images[index]);
              },
            )
        )
```

For more details on why the 'shrinkWrap' property is needed, you can refer to this : [What does the shrink wrap property do in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007073/what-does-the-shrink-wrap-property-do-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add shrinkWrap to your Gridview as follows :

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: images.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Image.network(images[index]);;
                },
              )
          )
```