# Flutter - Fixed button next to horizontal scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a dialog with a button and I want to add a horizontal scroll next to the button, so this way the button is fixed in the left and the scroll is in the right. I tried using a Row but I got the following error:

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
> Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
> .
> .
> .
> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#48cb5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'
> .
> .
> .

The specific code I used for this is the following:

```
      SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  AddUsersButton(newTaskCubit: newTaskCubit),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        UserExample(newTaskCubit: newTaskCubit),
                        UserExample(newTaskCubit: newTaskCubit),
                        UserExample(newTaskCubit: newTaskCubit),
                        UserExample(newTaskCubit: newTaskCubit),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `SizeBox()` `width` also and use `shrikWrap` with your `Listview` .As the scroll is `Horizontal` its asking for you a fixed `widht`.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shrinkWrap: true,` on `ListView`

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 80,
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[....],
  ),
```

You can check more about [What does the shrinkWrap property do in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54007073/10157127)