# Flutter How To Size Horizontal Scrollable In Vertical Layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble working out how to size a **horizontal** scrollable (`ListView`) within a vertical layout (a vertical `ListView` in this case).

I want the ListView to be as tall as its contents but am unsure how to achieve this with a horizontal scrollable.

For example:

```
ListView(
    children: [
        //How do I size this ListView to the height of its child?
        ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) Widget()],
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible. It would require the `ListView` to build every child to use the maximum height and this would go again the lazy loading behaviour of the `ListView`.

Comment: It seems you might be right. Do you know how I might achieve a similar effect without ListView? I.e a horizontal scrollable within a vertical one, without explicitly sizing the horizontal scrollable?

Comment: I faced the issue before and no, I didn't find a proper solution to this. With a `Row`, you can use `IntrinsicHeight` but it is expensive. With a `ListView`, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the inner ListView with a Container of `height: double.infinity`

You could wrap the outer ListView in a Container with a height you would like to set, this would set the height of the outer ListView and the inner ListView inside the container should expand this outer ListView's height.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `shrinkWrap: true`. It's explained in details in [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) and in another answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008230/16464074)

Comment: This doesn't fix the error in this case, where the scroll direction is horizontal. If you mean set shrinkwrap on the outer listview, this also doesn't work (probably because the inner one still isn't sized in the vertical direction).

Comment: Then you can try to use combination of SingleChildScrollView (with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal) and Row. In this way the widgets know their height and will expand the parent widget accordingly. It's not the best solution performance-wise but it does the trick