# How can I fill the height of the ListView.builder to fill the available space inside the scrollable view when shrinkwrap is true?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView.builder` that uses `shrinkWrap` because I get an error if I don't use it.

As a result of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008230/16124033), there will be a lot of white space above `ListView.builder`:

[image: The result of the answer]

How can I remove it?

My code:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        "Summary",
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          …
        ],
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        cacheExtent: 9999,
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(…),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How can I change the position of the `ListView.builder` that uses `shrinkWrap`?

Comment: Could you provide the entire code of the body of scaffold . Is this the only element in the body of scaffold ?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I shared more code

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly n this above updated code?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya at the bottom of the `Row`, there is a blank screen with `ListView.builder` below. I want to remove that blank screen

Comment: Okay now i get you, could you possible change your question title to `how to fill the listview's height to fill the available space inside scrollable view when shrinkwrap is true.` It makes more sense and clear, about your question, and it would draw more attention

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya any progress please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251455/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-my-car).

Comment: Wrap listview inside expanded

Answer (score 0):

I don't know by "space above `ListView.builder`" or "How can I change the position of the `ListView.builder` that uses `shrinkWrap`?" what you mean

Possible solutions considering all cases:

- If it's outside the `ListView` is because of wrapping it in `Center` which is obvious.
- If you are referring to the top margin inside the `ListView` it is because of this line `margin: EdgeInsets.all(32),`
- You just have to remove `Center` widget, it will change it's position to the start of the app.

Extra: You can remove the default `padding` of `ListView.builder` by adding `padding:EdgeInsets.zero`. If this is what you are talking about.

```
Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red), color: Colors.amber),
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: const <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
            ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
            ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
          ],
        ),
      )),
```

[image]

Note: You dont have to use `shrinkWrap:true` everytime , it is preferred to be used, only when your `listView` is inside another `Scrollable` view. Else it is preferred to be `false` which is the option by default

---

Refer the [docs:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html)

> Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes.

Answer (score 0):

add padding to the listview builder

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `ListView.builder`, you should use `Column`:

```dart
Column(
  children: list.map((element) => …).toList(),
),
```