# Listview.builder render all view issue if its child of ScrollView/ Listview/ Listview.builder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, rendering

As I have a view hierarchy that has a dynamic list widget (using listview.builder arround 100+ view same time), that child of  the Listview/ singlechildscrollview.

the issue is when its child of listview/ scroll view  at that time Listview.builder render all widget inside it.

### **I want render only view those displayed as listview.builder behave. (recycle when scroll)**

`runApp(MyApp( items: List<String>.generate(100, (i) => 'Item $i'), ));`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> items;
const MyApp({super.key, required this.items});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
const title = 'Long List';
return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        
        children: [
          Text("Test nexted List rendering"),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print(index);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(items[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
);
}
}
```

[image]

### Edited

The above example is just a sample, I **cant use parent as a Column** instead of Listview.
Because My **hierarchy is very big**. it's a **CMS kind of page** with around **3-4 parent Listview is there**.

`Listview > Listview > Listview > Listview.`

Answer (score 1):

`shrinkWrap: true` isnt good. You can use CustomScrolView.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.items});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Long List';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Text("Test nexted List rendering"),
            ),
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(childCount: items.length,
                    (context, index) {
              print(index);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(items[index]),
              );
            }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [ShrinkWrap vs Slivers | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0)

Or on your general case, if you like to have text always on top, use `body:Column` and `Expnaded(child:ListView` by removing `shrinkWrap: true`.

Comment: is custom scroll view recycle view when i scroll ?

Comment: yes, you can think of it this way

Answer (score 0):

Read here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists

> The standard ListView constructor works well for small lists. To work
> with lists that contain a large number of items, it’s best to use the
> ListView.builder constructor.
>
> In contrast to the default ListView constructor, which requires
> creating all items at once, the ListView.builder() constructor creates
> items as they’re scrolled onto the screen.

Your `ListView.builder` rendered all items its because the parent `ListView` is rendered all the children widget inside it.

Workaround:

change the `ListView` with `Column`

```
Column(
 childrem: [
    Expanded(child: ListView.builder)
  ]
)
```

Preview: only rendered 15 items inside listview builder eventhough its `shrinkwrap: true`

[image]

Comment: thats i know but i have to use Listview.builder inside Listview/ scrollview . thats  the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ListView with `shrinkWrap = true`. More about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007073/what-does-the-shrinkwrap-property-do-in-flutter).

Alternatives:

Column with property `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` and using `Flexible()` to let it expand as much space that it available to the children.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
     items.map((item) => Flexible(child: Text(item))).toList(),
  ],
)
```

Comment: no u not understand me.
I need listview builder to recycle view when scroll.
so i cant use colum