# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep getting this error when I try to run the app :

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#534a9 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
account_screen.dart:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#d2a6e relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
account_screen.dart:19
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

here is my code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Ads').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Image.asset('assets/images/facebook.png'),
                      title: Text(document['Title']),
                      subtitle: Text(document['Description']),
                      trailing: const Icon(Icons.car_crash),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList());
              })
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Do you really need to make it as s scroll view => column => list view? Why don't you directly make it a list view?

Comment: because I need the StramBuilder... and when I try to remove ScrollView and Column I receive the same error

Comment: I tried to simulate your code, and setting `shrinkWrap: true` in the list view resolved the issue for me... Is nothing changed after adding it? Same error?

Comment: Additionally, when removing both `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column` and making the `StreamBuilder` to be directly the body, it works the same!

Comment: yes I didnt notice that I added Expanded after it... it works now as you explained Thank you a lot man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ListView` tries to use all the available space but this space is infinite, which leads to the error. You can use `shrinkWrap` property to make the `ListView` using only the space needed by its children :

```
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true, // Add this
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
  ...
  }
).toList());
```

More about `shrinkWrap` here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008230/11244991

Comment: Try to use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, in your column